# GUI Unit Conversion Meters/Feet

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, computer-science, metrics

I have been working on the Tkinter module for a few weeks now and started writing a GUI. I have a problem when I press the calculate button it doesn't show anything. The goal for it is to show the conversion of 25 meters into feet when the user selects meters or when the user selects feet to convert to meters. I want it to work like in this video right here. Any help would be appreciated. https://youtu.be/1z41yet2DkI

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Length Converter")

def calculate(*args):
# Conversion of meters
   if choices == "meters":
       value = float(meters.get())
       feet.set(int(3.281 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
# Conversion of feet
   if choices == "feet":
       value = float(feet.get())
       meters.set(int(0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5) / 10000.0)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding= "25 25 25 25")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

meters = StringVar()
feet = StringVar()
n = StringVar()

input_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=meters)
input_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

choices = ttk.Combobox (root, width = 10, textvariable = n)
choices ['values'] = ('meters', 'feet')
choices.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equal to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)


for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When converting from meters to feet, the code updates the `StringVar` named `feet`, however that is not displayed anywhere in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does basically what you want. I renamed your `StringVar`s and added an additional one to hold the result.

```
rom tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    if choices.get() == 'meters':
        value = float(inp.get())
        result.set(int(3.281 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5) / 10000.0)
        units.set('feet')
    if choices.get() == 'feet':
        value = float(inp.get())
        result.set(int(0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5) / 10000.0)
        units.set('meters')

root = Tk()
root.title('Length Converter')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding='25 25 25 25')
mainframe.grid(sticky=(N, W, E, S))

inp = StringVar()
choice = StringVar()
result = StringVar()
units = StringVar()

input_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=inp)
input_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
choices = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, width=10, textvariable=choice, values=('meters', 'feet'))
choices.grid(row=1, column=1)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text='is equal to').grid(row=2, column=0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=result).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=units).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text='Calculate', command=calculate).grid(row=3, column=1)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```